# UICollectionView vertical flow doesn't center first cell when going back

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

Check [this video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xh0fwfxz0pargmg/PlayersVerticalSelectionView.mov?dl=0) to understand exactly my issue.

I have a custom view composition which contains a UICollectionView where the user can scroll using two buttons Up/Down. The values should be centered while changing, everything works great until I return back to the first value which appears much lower than the center. Note that I don't have any problem using the same approach for horizontal scrolling views.

My approach of centering the value, copied from centering the X axis, just changed the relevant sections for Y axis.

Created a UICollectionViewFlowLayout derived class and set to the UICollectioViewFlowLayout of the UICollectionView. Note that the override method is not invoked when scrolling programmatically.

```
[Register("CenterVerticalCellCollectionViewFlowLayout")]
public class CenterVerticalCellCollectionViewFlowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout
{
    public CenterVerticalCellCollectionViewFlowLayout(IntPtr ptr) : base(ptr)
    {

    }

    public override CGPoint TargetContentOffset(CGPoint proposedContentOffset, 
                                                CGPoint scrollingVelocity)
    {
        var cv = this.CollectionView;
        var cvBounds = cv.Bounds;
        var halfHeight = cvBounds.Height * 0.5;
        var proposedContentOffsetCenterY = proposedContentOffset.Y + halfHeight;
        var attributesForVisibleCells = LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect(cvBounds);
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes candidateAttributes = null;

        foreach (var attributes in attributesForVisibleCells)
        {
            // == Skip comparison with non-cell items (headers and footers) == //
            if (attributes.RepresentedElementCategory != UICollectionElementCategory.Cell)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if ((attributes.Center.Y == 0) || 
                (attributes.Center.Y > (cv.ContentOffset.Y + halfHeight) && 
                 scrollingVelocity.Y < 0))
            {
                continue;
            }

            // == First time in the loop == //
            if (candidateAttributes == null)
            {
                candidateAttributes = new UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes();
            }
            else
            {
                candidateAttributes = attributes;
                continue;
            }

            var a = attributes.Center.Y- proposedContentOffsetCenterY;
            var b = candidateAttributes.Center.Y - proposedContentOffsetCenterY;


            if (Math.Abs(a) < Math.Abs(b))
            {
                candidateAttributes = attributes;
            }
        }

        // Beautification step , I don't know why it works!
        if (proposedContentOffset.Y == -(cv.ContentInset.Top))
        {
            return proposedContentOffset;
        }

        if (candidateAttributes == null)
        {
            candidateAttributes = new UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes();
        }

        return new CGPoint(Math.Floor(candidateAttributes.Center.Y - 
            halfHeight), proposedContentOffset.Y);
    }
}
```

When loading the custom UIView I set the below.

```
CollectionView.ContentOffset = CGPoint.Empty;
```

In `UIViewController.ViewWillLayoutSubviews` I call the below method.

```
CollectionView.CollectionViewLayout.InvalidateLayout();
```

In `UIViewController.ViewDidLayoutSubviews` I call the below.

```
var insets = CollectionView.ContentInset;
var value = (View.Frame.Height - (CollectionView.CollectionViewLayout as UICollectionViewFlowLayout).ItemSize.Height) * 0.5;

insets.Top = (nfloat)value;
insets.Bottom = (nfloat)value;
CollectionView.ContentInset = insets;
CollectionView.DecelerationRate = UIScrollView.DecelerationRateFast;
```

And finally the code below for Up/Down programmatically scrolling.

```
partial void UpButtonTouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
{
    MoveSelectionCollectionViewCell();
}

partial void DownButtonTouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
{
    MoveSelectionCollectionViewCell(false);
}

void MoveSelectionCollectionViewCell(bool moveUp = true)
{
    var firstVisibleIndexPath = CollectionView.IndexPathsForVisibleItems.FirstOrDefault();

    if (firstVisibleIndexPath != null)
    {
        var row = moveUp ? firstVisibleIndexPath.Row + 1 : firstVisibleIndexPath.Row - 1;
        if (row > -1 &&
            row < _source.Collection.Count)
        {
            var scrollAtIndexPath = NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(row, 0);
            CollectionView.ScrollToItem(
                scrollAtIndexPath,
                UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredVertically,
                true);
        }
    }
}
```

See below the UICollectionView IB properties.

[image: IB Properties 1]
[image: IB Properties 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While reviewing my question made me realize the problem!

When in `UIViewController.ViewDidLayoutSubviews` calls the code it takes account of the `View.Frame.Height` which is wrong since the custom control View is not the same size of the `UICollectionView` hence demonstrating this issue.

Changing this:

```
var value = (View.Frame.Height - (CollectionView.CollectionViewLayout as UICollectionViewFlowLayout).ItemSize.Height) * 0.5;
```

To this:

```
var value = (CollectionView.Frame.Height - (CollectionView.CollectionViewLayout as UICollectionViewFlowLayout).ItemSize.Height) * 0.5;
```

Did the trick.